# Custom Precision-Recall AUC measure in mlr3

Tags: r, machine-learning, precision-recall, mlr3

I would like to create a custom Precision-Recall AUC measure in mlr3.

I am following the [mlr3 book chapter on creating custom measures.](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending-measures.html)

I feel I'm *almost* there, but R throws an annoying error that I don't know how to interpret.

Let's define the measure:

```
PRAUC = R6::R6Class("PRAUC",
  inherit = mlr3::MeasureClassif,
    public = list(
      initialize = function() {
        super$initialize(
          # custom id for the measure
          id = "classif.prauc",

          # additional packages required to calculate this measure
          packages = c('PRROC'),

          # properties, see below
          properties = character(),

          # required predict type of the learner
          predict_type = "prob",

          # feasible range of values
          range = c(0, 1),

          # minimize during tuning?
          minimize = FALSE
        )
      }
    ),

    private = list(
      # custom scoring function operating on the prediction object
      .score = function(prediction, ...) {

        truth1 <- ifelse(prediction$truth == levels(prediction$truth)[1], 1, 0) # Function PRROC::pr.curve assumes binary response is numeric, positive class is 1, negative class is 0
        PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob, weights.class0 = truth1)

      }
    )
)

mlr3::mlr_measures$add("classif.prauc", PRAUC)
```

Let's see if it works:

```
task_sonar <- tsk('sonar')
learner <- lrn('classif.rpart', predict_type = 'prob')
learner$train(task_sonar)
pred <- learner$predict(task_sonar)
pred$score(msr('classif.prauc'))

# Error in if (sum(weights < 0) != 0) { : 
#  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here's the traceback:

```
11.
check(length(sorted.scores.class0), weights.class0) 
10.
compute.pr(scores.class0, scores.class1, weights.class0, weights.class1, 
    curve, minStepSize, max.compute, min.compute, rand.compute, 
    dg.compute) 
9.
PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob, weights.class0 = truth1) 
8.
measure$.__enclos_env__$private$.score(prediction = prediction, 
    task = task, learner = learner, train_set = train_set) 
7.
measure_score(self, prediction, task, learner, train_set) 
6.
m$score(prediction = self, task = task, learner = learner, train_set = train_set) 
5.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
4.
vapply(.x, .f, FUN.VALUE = .value, USE.NAMES = FALSE, ...) 
3.
map_mold(.x, .f, NA_real_, ...) 
2.
map_dbl(measures, function(m) m$score(prediction = self, task = task, 
    learner = learner, train_set = train_set)) 
1.
pred$score(msr("classif.prauc"))
```

It seems like the glitch is coming from `PRROC::pr.curve`. However, when trying this function on the actual prediction object `pred`, it works just fine:

```
PRROC::pr.curve(
  scores.class0 = pred$prob[, 1], 
  weights.class0 =  ifelse(pred$truth == levels(pred$truth)[1], 1, 0)
)

#  Precision-recall curve
#
#    Area under curve (Integral):
#     0.9081261
#
#    Area under curve (Davis & Goadrich):
#     0.9081837 
#
#    Curve not computed ( can be done by using curve=TRUE )
```

One likely scenario why the error occurs is because, inside `PRAUC`, `PRROC::pr.curve`'s argument `weights.class0` is `NA`. I haven't been able to confirm this, but I'm suspecting that `weights.class0` is receiving `NA` instead of numeric, causing `PRROC::pr.curve` to malfunction inside `PRAUC`. If that's the case, I don't know why it's happening.

There may be other scenarios that I haven't thought of. Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

[missuse](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/extending-measures.html)'s, answer helped me realize why my measure isn't working. First,

`PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob, weights.class0 = truth1)`

should be

`PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob[, 1], weights.class0 = truth1)`.

Second, function `pr.curve` returns an object of class `PRROC`, while the `mlr3` measure I've defined is actually expecting `numeric`. So it should be

`PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob[, 1], weights.class0 = truth1)[[2]]`

or

`PRROC::pr.curve(scores.class0 = prediction$prob[, 1], weights.class0 = truth1)[[3]]`,

depending on the method used to compute the AUC (see `?PRROC::pr.curve`).

Note that although `MLmetrics::PRAUC` is far less confusing than `PRROC::pr.curve`, it seems like [the former is poorly implemented](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439883/the-precision-recall-aucs-calculated-by-two-different-packages-are-different).

Here's an implementation of the measure with `PRROC::pr.curve` that actually works:

```
PRAUC = R6::R6Class("PRAUC",
  inherit = mlr3::MeasureClassif,
    public = list(
      initialize = function() {
        super$initialize(
          # custom id for the measure
          id = "classif.prauc",

          # additional packages required to calculate this measure
          packages = c('PRROC'),

          # properties, see below
          properties = character(),

          # required predict type of the learner
          predict_type = "prob",

          # feasible range of values
          range = c(0, 1),

          # minimize during tuning?
          minimize = FALSE
        )
      }
    ),

    private = list(
      # custom scoring function operating on the prediction object
      .score = function(prediction, ...) {

        truth1 <- ifelse(prediction$truth == levels(prediction$truth)[1], 1, 0) # Looks like in mlr3 the positive class in binary classification is always the first factor level
        PRROC::pr.curve(
          scores.class0 = prediction$prob[, 1], # Looks like in mlr3 the positive class in binary classification is always the first of two columns
          weights.class0 = truth1
        )[[2]]

      }
    )
)

mlr3::mlr_measures$add("classif.prauc", PRAUC)
```

Example:

```
task_sonar <- tsk('sonar')
learner <- lrn('classif.rpart', predict_type = 'prob')
learner$train(task_sonar)
pred <- learner$predict(task_sonar)
pred$score(msr('classif.prauc'))

#classif.prauc 
#     0.923816
```

However, **the issue now is** that changing the positive class results in a different score:

```
task_sonar <- tsk('sonar')
task_sonar$positive <- 'R' # Now R is the positive class
learner <- lrn('classif.rpart', predict_type = 'prob')
learner$train(task_sonar)
pred <- learner$predict(task_sonar)
pred$score(msr('classif.prauc'))

#classif.prauc 
#    0.9081261
```

Comment: Even though `MLmetrics::PRAUC` might be inferior to `PRROC::pr.curve` the general idea of the implementation of the measure in mlr3 is the same. Its funny how I forgot [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53301729/difference-between-auprc-in-caret-and-prroc). You are correct that `prediction$prob[,1]` should be used since that corresponds to the positive class. As for the edited question, I am not sure where is the problem? Its like saying sensitivity changes when you change the positive class. This is inherent to the type of measure.

Comment: My bad. I thought PR AUC was symmetric like the standard ROC AUC. E.g. `MLmetrics::AUC(pred$data$prob[, 1], as.integer(pred$truth == "M")) == MLmetrics::AUC(pred$data$prob[, 2], as.integer(pred$truth == "R"))` is `TRUE`, while `MLmetrics::PRAUC(pred$data$prob[, 1], as.integer(pred$truth == "M")) == MLmetrics::PRAUC(pred$data$prob[, 2], as.integer(pred$truth == "R"))` is `FALSE`.

Comment: I eddied my answer to point to your implementation using `PRROC::pr.curve` which is more precise. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?PRROC::pr.curve` is rather confusing, so I will use `MLmetrics::PRAUC` to calculate PRAUC:

```
library(mlr3measures)
library(mlr3)

PRAUC = R6::R6Class("PRAUC",
                    inherit = mlr3::MeasureClassif,
                    public = list(
                      initialize = function() {
                        super$initialize(
                          # custom id for the measure
                          id = "classif.prauc",

                          # additional packages required to calculate this measure
                          packages = c('MLmetrics'),

                          # properties, see below
                          properties = character(),

                          # required predict type of the learner
                          predict_type = "prob",

                          # feasible range of values
                          range = c(0, 1),

                          # minimize during tuning?
                          minimize = FALSE
                        )
                      }
                    ),

                    private = list(
                      # custom scoring function operating on the prediction object
                      .score = function(prediction, ...) {

                        MLmetrics::PRAUC(prediction$prob[,1], #probs for 1st (positive class is in first column) class
                                         as.integer(prediction$truth == levels(prediction$truth)[1])) #truth for 1st class

                      }
                    )
)
```

To verify it works:

```
mlr3::mlr_measures$add("classif.prauc", PRAUC)
task_sonar <- tsk('sonar')
learner <- lrn('classif.rpart', predict_type = 'prob')
learner$train(task_sonar)
pred <- learner$predict(task_sonar)
pred$score(msr('classif.prauc'))
classif.prauc 
     0.8489383  

MLmetrics::PRAUC(pred$data$prob[,1],
                 as.integer(pred$truth == "M"))
0.8489383
```

EDIT: the measure implementation using `PRROC::pr.curve` is given as edit to the question above. It is advisable to use that implementation since `PRROC::pr.curve` is more precise compared to `MLmetrics::PRAUC`.